# Prevent PMD from printing violations twice

Tags: java, maven, pmd

I have a Java 7 project being built by Maven 3.2.1. I'm analyzing my source code at build time using [PMD](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/) (`maven-pmd-plugin:3.2`, which uses `net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd:5.1.2` under the hood).

Given a simple class with one violation, my Maven output has that exact violation printed twice, but I don't want duplicate violations because it's misleading and harder to read.

### My Source Code

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

### My `pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>pmd-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <linkXref>false</linkXref>
                    <sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding>
                    <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
                    <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
                    <minimumPriority>2</minimumPriority>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/logging-java.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <failurePriority>2</failurePriority>
                    <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### Maven output

```
mvn prepare-package
```

---

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building pmd-test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ pmd-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ pmd-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Projects\pmd-test\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ pmd-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ pmd-test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ pmd-test ---
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-pmd-plugin:3.2:check (default) @ pmd-test >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.2:pmd (pmd) @ pmd-test ---
[WARNING] Unable to locate Source XRef to link to - DISABLED
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-pmd-plugin:3.2:check (default) @ pmd-test <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.2:check (default) @ pmd-test ---
[INFO] PMD Failure: Main:4 Rule:SystemPrintln Priority:2 System.out.println is used.
[INFO] PMD Failure: Main:4 Rule:SystemPrintln Priority:2 System.out.println is used.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.161 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-06T20:21:41-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/308M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.2:check (default) on project pmd-test: You have 1 PMD violation. For more details see:C:\Projects\pmd-test\target\pmd.xml -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Specifically, it prints

```
[INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.2:check (default) @ pmd-test ---
[INFO] PMD Failure: Main:4 Rule:SystemPrintln Priority:2 System.out.println is used.
[INFO] PMD Failure: Main:4 Rule:SystemPrintln Priority:2 System.out.println is used.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

but I want it to print

```
[INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.2:check (default) @ pmd-test ---
[INFO] PMD Failure: Main:4 Rule:SystemPrintln Priority:2 System.out.println is used.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

### What I've tried

- I upgraded to `maven-pmd-plugin:3.6`, which is the latest as of July 6, 2016, which did not change the output.
- I extracted the relevant pieces from my real project into the example above, to make sure that a minimal project can reproduce the issue, which it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was caused by my misconfiguration of the Maven PMD Plugin.

To fix the issue so each violation is only printed once, change the configuration of `maven-pmd-plugin` to disable either `printFailingErrors` or `verbose`. They both default to `false`, so removing either element will solve the issue.

### Example fixed plugin configuration in `pom.xml`

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <linkXref>false</linkXref>
        <sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding>
        <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
        <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
        <minimumPriority>2</minimumPriority>
        <rulesets>
            <ruleset>/rulesets/java/logging-java.xml</ruleset>
        </rulesets>
        <failurePriority>2</failurePriority>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I think that verbose mode should only print errors or warnings that would not have otherwise been printed, to make it consistent with every other logging system ever made, but here we are.